# ContinueTrackingWithTouch doesn't get called continuously

Tags: ios, uicontrol

I am creating a subclass of `UIControl` and adding to my view controller's view

```
- (BOOL) beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (BOOL) continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void) endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

when I touch and track inside of view the `continueTrackingWithTouch`get called continuously but some point it doesn't get called even If I am tracking...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: try this - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

Comment: - (void)cancelTrackingWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event; this method get called after that only continueTrackingWithTouch doesn't get called

Comment: Please try the answer i gave i used this code for signature feature. this code will help for continuous tracking of touch

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had the same problem, check if one of your superviews has gesture recogniser, and deactivate them when you need to user the UIControl.

I actually ended changed the superview of the UIControl to avoid this conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This the below code is for signature feature this will help you to see how to track touch continuously 

CGPoint lastPoint;
BOOL mouseSwiped;
int mouseMoved;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
mouseSwiped = NO;
/*  The below statements will help to get the exact point user touches with out this it will take ZERO yaxis  */
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:signatureImageView]; // replace signatureImageView with your view
lastPoint.y -= 20;     
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
mouseSwiped = YES;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:signatureImageView];// replace signatureImageView with your view
currentPoint.y -= 20;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signatureImageView.frame.size);
[signatureImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, signatureImageView.frame.size.width, signatureImageView.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapButt);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
signatureImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;

mouseMoved++;
if (mouseMoved == 20) {
    mouseMoved = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: touchesMoved doesn't get called at some point of time. This method get called cancelTrackingWithEvent I think this is the reason for continueTrackingWithTouch not being called

Comment: may i know for what feature your are using touches method? the above 2 methods are enough to track user touches. if you use cancelTrackingWithEvent user should not stop touching screen until his work is done

Comment: It is not a matter that which delegate method we are using the problem is cancelTrackingWithEvent get called so only touchesMoved doesn't get called